# CartoDB Mouse Scroll Wheel not Zooming

Tags: carto, zoom

Here is my CartoDB map:
https://tekim.cartodb.com/viz/1f42eaae-cad0-11e5-8e5c-0ecfd53eb7d3/public_map

I have enabled (Options -> Scroll Wheel Zoom).  Once I do this, I am able to use the scroll wheel to zoom as long as I am logged into CartoDB. However, the people with whom I am sharing the map cannot use the scroll wheel to zoom, and if I am logged out, I can't either. I am using Chrome and I have tested in IE 11 and both exhibit this issue. What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll wheel zoom option is enabled when you view the map in full screen mode.

So, you might want to share your link that shows the full screen map (https://tekim.cartodb.com/viz/1f42eaae-cad0-11e5-8e5c-0ecfd53eb7d3/embed_map).

Comment: Thanks, that works.  To get the link, click on the "publish" button, click on the "Go to your map" link under "Embed it", and copy the URL from the address bar of your browser.